# MATLAB not "seeing" Intel Cluster Studio XE

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-2012, fortran

I'm helping someone with MATLAB 2013B (Windows) on a machine that has the Intel Cluster Studio XE installed.

However, when using MATLAB and typing "`mex -setup`" MATLAB does not see the Intel Cluster Studio installed, and thus cannot be chosen to compile some older Fortran code. It only sees the Microsoft Visual Studio, which is also installed.

Any ideas or suggestions? I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance, Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps Intel Cluster Studio is not seen by MATLAB as the same thing as Intel Composer, which is supported by MATLAB.  [Here is the list of supported compilers](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013b/index.html) for the current version of MATLAB.  If the same compiler is included with Cluster Studio, you can use `intelc13msvs2012opts.bat` as a template to try and get Cluster Studio support. It may be as simple as setting the `ICPP_COMPILER13` environment variable and using that .bat file verbatim, copied to `%APPDATA%\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2013b\mexopts.bat`.

**EDIT**: Note that the file needs to be renamed to `mexopts.bat` when it is copied to the new location.

Comment: thanks, I'll give that a try and be in touch! Much appreciated.

Comment: @Dan - I forgot to mention that you have to also rename the file to `mexopts.bat` when you copy it.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Turns out we needed to install the compiler version that MATLAB requires, which resolved this issue.